# How to merge a forked branch

Tags: git, gitlab

I tried looking from other answers but I am still unsure.

Let's assume I forked the repository https://github.com/test/test.git.
Setting that remote as 'upstream' and my fork is the 'origin'.

'upstream' has a branch called 'test_phase_1', which I have fetched and worked upon.

Which series of command will lead to the safest and most correct way to commit, push my work to origin and merge to upstream?

Sorry for being a little vague but I am really new to git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Committing and pushing your local changes in branch `test_phase_1` would end up in remote branch `origin/test_phase_1`

Go to the upstream repo and create a pull request with *your* branch using the `upstream/test_phase_1` as base branch (which may be `master` by default), if you want your changes to be *merged* into the `upstream/test_phase_1` branch. Else let it remain as `master`